# Basic Django - Custom Managers

Tags: python, django

I'm going through the [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10/) and I'm currently on [chapter 10](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10/). I'm having a problem understanding the third line in this fragment of code:

```
class DahlBookManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(DahlBookManager, self).get_query_set().filter(author='Roald Dahl')
```

I understand that this custom manager instance is overriding the superclass' `get_query_set` method, but why is the `super` call passing in both `DahlBookManager` as well as `self`? Aren't `self` and `DahlBookManager` the same thing?

Comment: This is a question about basic Python, not Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about the builtin Super() function in Python.

You can get a reference here: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html

> If the second argument is omitted, the
>   super object returned is unbound.

Answer (score 0):

No, `self` is an instance of `DahlBookManager`. `super()` uses the class to handle things like MRO, inheritance, etc.